Item's Display only working for first item
Figure 1 - Issue 
Each item's buttons is connected to a display which pop up only for the first item.
The display is a fragment1.xml and the recylerview (the container holding each item) is inside mainactivity.xml and the item of the recyclerview is created in another fragment2.xml.
Figure 2 - Expectation
I'm expecting the display to show for their perspective item when a button is selected.
I've tried using Log.d to see if there is connection issue but logcat states the correct id for the items butons. I've rewrote the function of display to take 2 parameters, both id, but had the same issue. I have a button that would change the color for the item's background and it works.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
